# Split ZipCode record ranges to separate cells

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

Creating a Domestic Zone Chart of Zip Codes based on their first 3 digits.

I have a list of the USPS Zone chart but I need to split the zip ranges out.

**Original file (excel) looks like:**

- **(col A)**     |      **(col B)**
- **ZIP Code   |     Zone**
- 018--019          6
- 010---065         7

**Desired Output (excel)**

- **Zip Code |  Zone**
- 018             6
- 019             6
- 010             7
- 011             7
- (thru)065       7

[excel image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XYTZ1.png)

Comment: Python, excel and vba tags together seems a bit much. Also, we don't know what  your original data looks like (is it an Excel document?), and how you expect the output to be (Excel column? Python list? ... ?). Please clarify your question.

Comment: Sorry, I have updated the post as it should not of had the tag python. I also added that this is an excel file noting the original, and desired output.  Also provided image screenshot.

Comment: Have you made any attempt to figure this out? Are you getting an error? What's the actual issue?  (See **How to create a [mcve]**)

Comment: No, sorry I am actually not sure where to start to extract a range (010---065) and seperate these as if they are their own rows 010 through 065.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're looking for any solution and not just a python one, here's one for excel:
Code for row B:

```
=LEFT(A1,3)
```

Code for row C:

```
=RIGHT(A1,1)
```

Code for row D:

```
=CONCATENATE(B1," ",C1)
```

Sould give you

```
     A        B    C     D  
018--019 6   018   6   018 6
```

Hope this helps you.